# Customizable static call graph for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, call-graph

Is there some sort of API or plugin that allows me to first generate a call graph for a java project in Eclipse and to customize specific aspects, such as color, of individual methods within the graph? I'm trying to implement a plugin that creates a call graph that has been tweaked based on outside input.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10996108/120163

Answer (score 1):

Your right: there is an plugin on sourceforge (http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364402/Code-Analysis-with-the-Eclipse-Profiler). You can download the sources and you can contribute the development of the plugin.

Have fun!

Comment: This looks good, but I'm actually looking for something to generate a **static** call graph, and it looks like this one is a dynamic graph.